# How to make json from a nested ul li using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-lists

I have a dynamic nested ul li like,

```
<div id="data">
    <ul>
        <li><span>1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>1.1</span></li>
                <li><span>1.2</span></li>
                <li><span>1.3</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>1.3.1</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>2</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to convert this nested list to json like below

```
{
    "1": {
        "1.1": "val",
        "1.2": "val",
        "1.3": {
            "1.3.1": "val"
        }
    },
    "2": "val"
}
```

How can I do that? I have tried with some recursive algorithms, but I couldn't find out the exact recursive logic of this.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I tried..

```
function test() {
    data = {}
    testRecur($("#data").children('ul'), data);
    console.log(data.toSource());
}

function testRecur(next, data) {
    var newDataJson = {}
    $(next).children('li').each(function (idx, element) {
        value = $(element).children('span').first().html();
        if ($(element).find('ul').length > 0) {
            data[value] = testRecur($(element).find('ul').first(), data);
        } else {
            newDataJson[value] = "val";
        }
    });
    return newDataJson;
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You said that your tried something then show it please

Comment: Recursion would seem to be Recursion would seem to be the most appropriate pattern to use here the most appropriate pattern to use here